# Print function values

Tags: python

Print the values of the function `y = (x ^ 2/2) -4x`, with x from -3 to -1 in increments of 0.2

Comment: This site is for questions in English only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

x_range = np.arange(-3, -0.8, 0.2)
for x in x_range:
  y = (x**2)/2 - 4*x
  print("{:.2f} -> {:.2f}".format(x, y))
```

if you want to store the y values for each x:

```
import numpy as np

x_range = np.arange(-3, -0.8, 0.2)
y_vals = []
for x in x_range:
  y = (x**2)/2 - 4*x
  y_vals.append(y)

print(np.around(y_vals, decimals=2))
```

without numpy:

```
y_vals = []
for x in range(-30,-8,2):
  x /= 10.0 # can't have floats in range()
  y = (x**2)/2 - 4*x
  y_vals.append(y)

print(y_vals)
```

Comment: "Is it possible to write code without using third-party libraries?" 
See my response above (without numpy)